# I need help finding a web element in selenium Java

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="ember354" class="ember-view ember-text-field search" placeholder="Ask me anything!" type="text">
```

Which is reached from body-div-div-input

- I can't find the element by tag due to there being more than 1 input tag
- I can't find the element by id due to it being dynamic
- I can't find the element by class due to compound class name
- I've tried many different CSS selectors with no success
- I've tried many different XPATH lines with no success

Different variations of this code replacing * with input and using contains & starts-with functions were of no use:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ember-view ember-text-field search']"));
```

Different CSS selectors like this were used including contains and other functions were of no success either

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ember-view.ember-text-field.search"));
```

I thought maybe searching by placeholder since that is static would be a good idea but I do not know how to go about that.

Comment: Both queries should work. What is the method returning?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: Does the page create that element dynamically?

Comment: Is this element inside an iframe.

Comment: No, the full path is literally //body/div/div/input

Comment: "Many different" does not provide any insight on what did not work, and why. List them, and add what went wrong. Is _any_ of that HTML classes unique to this input? Is the `@id` attribute unique in the prefix "ember" (disregarding the digits in the end)?

Comment: Well when I say many, I mean I've probably exhausted every answer I found in other threads. It's hard to list all the things I've tried. the ID attribute is changing but ember remains the same. I've tried to do a contains "ember" search though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to find element by its placeholder

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Ask me anything!']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake with css selector. 
I think you forgot to put **`.`** in front of class name while using css selector.

Correct css locator would be `.ember-view.ember-text-field.search`

So your final code look like :

```
String cssLocator = ".ember-view.ember-text-field.search";
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssLocator));
```

or if you want to make it more specific then you can use:

`String cssLocator = ".ember-view[placeholder='Ask me anything!']";` also